# Select data from tow table using LINQ in Asp Core razor pages

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core

I have two table:

```
 public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

 }
```

and:

```
public class UsersAccessDepartments
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

The data looks like:
Department

```
1   Management      
2   Finiance    
5   Reciption
```

UsersAccessDepartments:

```
1   9c424b6e-fd57-4be7-b47a-2db67b29f651    1
2   9c424b6e-fd57-4be7-b47a-2db67b29f651    2
3   9c424b6e-fd57-4be7-b47a-2db67b29f651    3007
4   9c424b6e-fd57-4be7-b47a-2db67b29f651    3008
5   c4beb529-bb86-439e-a375-4f4cce3f9054    1
6   c4beb529-bb86-439e-a375-4f4cce3f9054    2
7   247779db-ad5f-4128-ae40-7f44cc3c0c71    3007
```

Id like to select the departments with new filed shows either the asked user is in department or not:
this the SQL and it's work:

```
Select D.Id, D.Name,
IIF((select UA.Id from UsersAccessDepartments UA where UA.DepartmentId=D.Id and  
UA.UserId='247779db-ad5f-4128-ae40-7f44cc3c0c71') is null ,
'false','true') Selected
from Department D
```

These what results looks :

```
Id     Name         Selected
1      Management   false
2      Finiance     false
5      Reciption    false
2005    CFO         false
3007    IT          true
3008    Cashier     true
```

In asp.core razor pages I can only use:

```
db.Department.FromSql(sql)
```

which accepted fileds from one table.
Or I have to use:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

which isn't return data.
the last option available to use ADO.Net

```
   command.CommandText = "Your Sql Query";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something with result
    }
```

and I don't want to use this one.
My Question:

Can i run above sql using EF core?

how to create Linq statement equivalent to my above select query?

Answer (score 1):

I found this linq do the work for me:

```
(from c in _db.Department
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                     Text = c.Name,
                                     Selected = (from UA in _db.UsersAccessDepartments
                                                where UA.UserId== TheUser.Id && UA.DepartmentId==c.Id
                                                select UA.Id).Count()==0? false: true
                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice work. As for the other question of `Can i run above sql using EF core?`, simply add a property of `public DbQuery<DepartmentUASelected> DepartmentUASelecteds { get; set; }` for your `AppDbContext`, and then run `var y=_context.Query<DepartmentUASelected>().FromSql(@"
Select 
    D.Id,
    D.Name,
    IIF(
        (select UA.Id
            from UsersAccessDepartments UA
            where UA.DepartmentId = D.Id and UA.UserId = '247779db-ad5f-4128-ae40-7f44cc3c0c71'
        ) is null,
        CAST( 0 as BIT ),
        CAST( 1 as BIT )
    ) Selected
from Department D").ToList();`

Comment: The trick is, to get a bool value, use `CAST(1 as bit)` / ` `CAST(0 as bit)`

Comment: That's great to cast 0,1 for bool. But the cool is I understand that I can use whatever sql in FromSql but return only fields from the used class. Thanks